# Expect script collect output in file

Tags: linux, expect

I have following expect script, its running /tmp/find_users.sh script on remote host and i am trying to collect output of that script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 3
if {[llength $argv] != 1} {
    puts "usage: ssh-auto host"
    exit 1
}

set host  [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $host
expect "passphrase"
send "XXXXXXX\r"
expect "$"
send  "/tmp/find_users.sh\r"
expect eof
```

I am using following method to collect output of script.

```
./auto-ssh.ex servername > command_output.txt
```

Problem is in output its appending server prompt and banner other craps.. I want neat output not crap.. I am sure there is a good way but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your remote shell to add log output to a file. And at the end of your expect script to get the log file using auto_scp.

Comment: Sure, no a bad idea but it seems, there is no easy way out of this problem.